# PowerShell's output of nested data types

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a nested data structure from some input and eventually convert it to JSON, but I am having trouble once it gets too deep.

The structure will be an array of a hash where one item is another array of a hash.

This sets up two arrays of a hash `$baz1` and `$baz2`

```
PS D:\> $baz1 = @(@{foo="foo1"; bar="bar1"};@{foo="foo2";bar="bar2"};@{foo="foo3";bar="bar3"})
PS D:\> $baz2 = @(@{foo="foo1"; bar="bar1"};@{foo="foo2";bar="bar2"};@{foo="foo3";bar="bar3"})
```

As you can see, all above board:

```
PS D:\> $baz1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
bar                            bar1
foo                            foo1
bar                            bar2
foo                            foo2
bar                            bar3
foo                            foo3


PS D:\> $baz1|ConvertTo-Json
[
    {
        "bar":  "bar1",
        "foo":  "foo1"
    },
    {
        "bar":  "bar2",
        "foo":  "foo2"
    },
    {
        "bar":  "bar3",
        "foo":  "foo3"
    }
]
PS D:\>
```

But when I add the array to `$fuz` it all goes pear-shaped:

```
PS D:\> $fuz = @(@{foo="bar"; bash=$baz1};@{foo="beep";bash=$baz2})
PS D:\> $fuz

Name                           Value
----                           -----
foo                            bar
bash                           {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable}
foo                            beep
bash                           {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable}


PS D:\> $fuz|ConvertTo-Json
[
    {
        "foo":  "bar",
        "bash":  [
                     "System.Collections.Hashtable",
                     "System.Collections.Hashtable",
                     "System.Collections.Hashtable"
                 ]
    },
    {
        "foo":  "beep",
        "bash":  [
                     "System.Collections.Hashtable",
                     "System.Collections.Hashtable",
                     "System.Collections.Hashtable"
                 ]
    }
]
```

Even without the `$baz1` step

```
PS D:\> @(@{foo="bar"; bash=@(@{foo="foo1"; bar="bar1"};@{foo="foo2";bar="bar2"};@{foo="foo3";bar="bar3"})};@{foo="beep";bash=$baz2})

Name                           Value
----                           -----
foo                            bar
bash                           {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable}
foo                            beep
bash                           {System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable}


PS D:\>
```

Really appreciate some help here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-Depth` parameter on the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet to expand the child property values.

Comment: As the output was also shallow I didn't think to look at the ConvertTo-json parameters.